# Dockerized Nginx stops immediately when in detached mode

Tags: docker, nginx, docker-compose

I have a dockerized Nginx as web server/proxy for dockerized Angular and ASP.NET Core web applications. For some reason, Nginx exits immediately. Here's the command generated and executed by Visual Studio 2019 when debugging:

```
docker-compose  -f "C:\Users\Me\source\repos\MySolution\docker-compose.yml" -f "C:\Users\Me\source\repos\MySolution\docker-compose.override.yml" -f "C:\Users\Me\source\repos\MySolution\obj\Docker\docker-compose.vs.debug.g.yml" -p dockercompose1472566653957529852 --no-ansi up -d --build --force-recreate --remove-orphans
```

Here's my docker-compose.yml file:

```
version: '3.7'

services:
  webapi.myproject:
    image: ${DOCKER_REGISTRY-}webapimyproject
    build:
      context: .
      dockerfile: WebApi.MyProject/Dockerfile

  ng.myproject:
    image: ${DOCKER_REGISTRY-}ngmyproject
    working_dir: '/app'
    build:
      context: ./NgMyProject
      dockerfile: Dockerfile
    volumes:
      - './NgMyProject:/app'
      - '/app/node_modules'
    environment:
      - CHOKIDAR_USEPOLLING=true 
      - NODE_ENV=dev

  proxy:
    image: nginx:latest
    ports:
      - "80:80"
    volumes:
      - ./nginx.conf:/etc/nginx/nginx.conf
    stdin_open: true
    tty: true
```

I added the last two line to try to keep Nginx from exiting but it looks like it has no effect.

Comment: better to post logs `docker logs` or `docker compose logs` without error how to catch the error in air ;)

Comment: @Adiii I tried to use `docker-compose logs` command but there's no specific error showing. I just re-run the command and it looks like Nginx's container is running fine now. But after I rebuild or clean the docker-compose project then run again, Nginx exits immediately. But there's a low chance it will keep running on the next attempts.

Comment: Better to run the compose manually , you can replace the DOCKER_REGISTRY with the appropriate value and run it locally , the logs will come on the console in that case.

Comment: @SoumenMukherjee it is unavoidable because when I run the project for debugging, it will auto-generate the file `\obj\Docker\docker-compose.vs.debug.g.yml` that will greatly help me debug my whole application. And when debugging, it will execute the whole command, so manually running it will become useless.